# Changing Linux VirtualBox 'parent' machine folder

Tags: fedora, virtualbox

I installed VirtualBox on Fedora 25 via

```
dnf install VirtualBox-5.1
```

and I am running into a problem where my previously installed version of it (VirtualBox-5.1.8-2.fc25.x86_64) was pointing to a directory which no longer exists on my file system. I am presented with the error (after clicking 'New' and going through the config process):

```
Cannot create the machine folder win7 in the parent folder /run/media/esoup/1234567890/VirtualMachines/vdi. 
Please check that the parent really exists and that you have permissions to create the machine folder.
```

I tried :

```
vboxmanage setproperty machinefolder /path/to/newdirectorywhichexists/
```

To no avail. The worst part is, the toolbar in the main application window does not work, Clicking File, Machine, and Help does nothing! [image]

Thank you for any assistance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the guide [here](http://blog.scottlowe.org/2017/02/07/installing-virtualbox-51-fedora-25/) , I first used `dnf remove VirtualBox-5.1` and then followed the guide, resulting in my VirtualBox to now allow me to click the toolbar and set my Machine Folder to a suitable location. There was something wrong with the previous dnf install in terms of how the VirtualBox kernel modules were loading.